# How to make a request to local URL as part of automated tests?

Tags: django, django-unittest

I'm writing an automated test in Django to check that a webhook is working on the application. The test sends a bunch of JSON to the webhook and will check that the call has been logged in the database. The problem I'm hitting however is that the test calls the http://localhost URL and the data is thus saved in my local dev database and not in the temporary database created by the test. So I now have no way to check the call has been received.

Whats the right solution for this?

```
from django.test import TestCase
import requests
from monzo.models import Transaction, RequestLog

class WebhookChecks(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['db.json', ]
    def test_simple_expense(self):

        my_json = '{"type": "transaction.created", REMOVED FOR SECURITY }'

        url = 'http://localhost/some_url/webhook/'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        r = requests.post(url, data=my_json, headers=headers)

        if not "200" in str(r):
            print("Something didn't work out. Error: "+str(r))

        self.assertTrue("200" in str(r))
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Djangos [Client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#making-requests) with which you can perform requests in your tests.

Example:

```py
from django.test import Client

c = Client()
c.get('/some_url/..')
```

---

Another way is to use Djangos [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase).

You can use `self.live_server_url` instead of directly writing `http://localhost`.

This testcase sets up a live server which listens to localhost.

Comment: No need for  a LiveServerTestCase here - it will work just as well with the test client (well, it should at least).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers right, adjusted the answer to use the built-in `Client`.

Comment: I used the LiveServerTestCase which worked fine. With the built in Client() could that be used to POST JSON though?

Comment: @rcx935 As of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) you should be able to post json, yes.